# What is the full form of the following sloka?

Tags: identification-request, manu-smriti

Swami Vivekananda has once quoted one line from a sloka which is most probably from the Manu-samhita, that reads

> charen mAdhukarim vrittim api mlechchhakulad api,
>
> Meaning : [a monk]  should beg food even from the foreigners.

Can someone provide the full sloka with source?

Comment: Can you include where Swami Vivekananda quoted this shloka in his work?

Comment: Swami-Sishya -Samvad

Comment: I hv used that verse in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20569) answer .. so it is from Atri Smriti/Samhita @Pratimaputra

Comment: @Rickross okay thanks.Are you sure such a sloka is not there in the Manu-smriti?

Comment: Probably not .. going by the portion u quoted (mlecchakula, madhukari vritti ) and the translation I hv given it seems the same verse from Atri Smriti .. but I don't hv the Sanskrit verse to answer @Pratimaputra